# Looking for string values by name in JSoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

So, I'm having a  problem in JSoup.

I need to parse an HTML page for a few form input values, that would look like this:

```
<input value="210cf5f0c2db3ac6ac5112881525cfff" data-value="1355317682" type="hidden" name="token" />
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="18c03bc9nkedyyjmbzgvmkv5tx7yhyw1" />
<input value="" name="redirect" type="hidden" />
<input value="d3edfe5b37608758516833b858b51b63" type="hidden" name="eyhy7xt5v" />
```

I need to be able to grab the values of each of these inputs, but one at a time. My current Java code looks like this:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

class JSoupTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://url.com/auth").get();
        Elements inputs = doc.select("input");
        for(Element input : inputs) {
            System.out.println(input.attr("name"));
            System.out.println(input.attr("value"));
        }
    }
}
```

It currently dumps all of the input's names, and their values, but I need the program to only output the value of a certain input field.

Like, say I wanted to output the value of the input field with the name "sid". I would need just that value printed, none of the others.

I just need to somehow do selective printing like that, I guess you could say. Just print the value of a certain input field.

Does anyone know how to do this?

In the JSoup documentation I had been looking at [this page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax/), but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Thanks!

EDIT: I just realized, the name of the last value is randomly generated each time you refresh the page. Is there any way to grab it if it doesn't have any values that stay constant besides the "hidden" characteristic?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you properly the following code does what you want:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MyParser {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputText = 
            "<input value=\"210cf5f0c2db3ac6ac5112881525cfff\" data-value=\"1355317682\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"token\" />"
            + "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sid\" value=\"18c03bc9nkedyyjmbzgvmkv5tx7yhyw1\" />"
            + "<input value=\"\" name=\"redirect\" type=\"hidden\" />"
            + "<input value=\"d3edfe5b37608758516833b858b51b63\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"eyhy7xt5v\" />" ;
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(inputText);
        Element body = doc.body();
        // Grab the value attribute of the INPUT element with a given name attribute
        Element input = body.select("input[name=sid]").first();
        System.out.println(input.attr("value"));
        // Grab the value attribute of the last INPUT element
        Element lastInput = body.select("input").last();
        System.out.println(lastInput.attr("value"));
    }
}
```

You can select an `input` element with a given value for the `name` attribute using the following syntax:

```
element.select("tag_name[attr_name=value]")
```

This returns an `Elements` object that contains just one element (because the value of the `name` attribute is unique).

You said that the `input` element with a changing `name` attribute is the the last `input` so you can take advantage of that knowledge by getting the `Elements` object containing all the `input` elements and taking the last of those elements.